# simultanious connection of spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I would like to use a spreadsheet to show data to 50000 to 100000 people at a time so Can Any One tell me how many people can download the json file of a spreadsheet at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The Sheets API has a  has a default limit of 40,000 queries per day. 
You also have

```
Write/Read requests per 100 seconds  500 
Write/Read requests per 100 seconds per user 100 
Write/Read requests per day  40,000
```

As long as you don't exceed those, you'll be fine. However if you go past the limit, you need to [create a billing account](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653) so you can ask for additional  quota.